# PHP: comparing mixed field

Tags: php

How can I make a comparison of a field that can either be string or integer?  I am getting very weird results, PHP interpreting the values are different when they are equal, etc.

I tried:

```
if ($value != $value2)
```

and also

```
if ($value !== $value2)
```

But in both cases I get the issue (for example 1.4536 keeps being not equal to 1.4536 for some reason, I don't really know why)

Comment: Use `===`, wich compares the value and type of both variables.

Comment: Erm, 1.4536 IS equal to 1.4536.  I'm not sure I understand what your question is.

Comment: @Phoenix, probably he was talking about two real different variables (ex : integer & string), but it's wise to clear that up OP.

Answer (score 0):

Type-cast them both into one type. For instance:

```
if ((int)$value1 != (int)$value2) { ... }
```

Comment: value could be a string though sometimes

Comment: @luqita: Then cast them both to strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `===`, which will not only compare values but variable types as well, thus solving your problem :

```
$s1 = '1.4536';
$s2 = 1.4536;

if ($s1 === $s2)
  echo 'passed';
else
  echo 'failed';
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your variables are casted into numbers, use [`floatval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) or [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).

Also, When comparing float values, it is a good practise to check their difference like this:

```
<?php
if (abs(floatval($s1)-floatval($s2)) < 0.00001) {
  echo 'passed';
} else {
  echo 'failed';
}
```